# In rxjs, I try to fetch all the data first then I need to proceed to next line

Tags: json, angular, rxjs, observable, fetchall

In Angular 5, I have observable array in service and I am subscribing this in component. And in the next line of statement I am checking whether the data was populated or not. But I found variable is not populated yet.

https://github.com/vsaravanan/ngx-mat-select-search.git

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
Error @  this.filteredBanksMulti.next(this.banks.slice());

I have a sample data running from jsonserver @ port 3000

```
        "banks"  :
        [
            { "name" : "apphugIndia", "id": "A"},
            { "name" : "batHugFr", "id": "B"},
            { "name" : "Bank C (France)", "id": "C"},
            { "name" : "hungary", "id": "D"},
            { "name" : "Hungary", "id": "E"},
            { "name" : "Bank F (Italy)", "id": "F"}
        ]
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you show us an example of your code? Also, be sure to do the check -in- the subscribe method. The data does not exist anymore outside of the subscribe method

Comment: is that worked for you ??

Comment: yes. solved. once moved into subscribe(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are doing like this

```
this.httpCall.getData().subscribe(data=>this.recoreds = data);
this.records
```

then its not going to work as , you call to server is still not complete you must need to wait for data to populate , that means you can do operation in `subscribe` method only.

to avoid issue you need to put you code in subscribe

```
this.httpCall.getData().subscribe(data=> {
      this.records = data;
      //do code here which uses  this.records
 });
```

Comment: ok. I can wait for data fetch to complete before the line "this.records". May I know to how to solve that?

Comment: you can, inside "subscribe" function, use a boolean variable "yetLoaded=true". (use this variable and *ngIf to show/hide a message "loading"). NOTE: in your code, I see that you're join service and component in the same file.ts -separate them an create two file.ts- and I see too that you're using the "old" and "deprecated" http, use httpClient instead of http

Comment: @singaporesaravanan - updated my answer please have look

Comment: I agree to the answers. But not sure how effectively I can put all the following statements within that subscribe function. Let me try. Thanks.